# MongoDB driver ruby, remove field in document

Tags: ruby, mongodb-ruby

I am triying remove field in a big document, therefore I would like to do something:

```
collection.update({'_id' => @id},  {"$unset" => {'herField'})
```

But it is not possible. I don't want to rewrite entire document, any idea?

EDIT: I am using https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax looks slightly incorrect. As per docs:

```
collection.update( { _id: @id }, { $unset: { herField: true } }, { multi: true });
```

Need the 'multi' option if you want to update multiple documents. E.g. from all records on this collection.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/unset/#op._S_unset

Comment: I am using https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver. And I'm just editing one document.

Comment: @ie8888: Does it work if you use something in the `$unset` that's truthy in the JavaScript sense? Say `{ $unset: { herField: true }`.

Comment: I am not using Javascript, I am using Ruby. When I ran my code, I get  Invalid modifier specified: $unset (Mongo::OperationFailure)

Comment: @ie8888: Yes, I know that, but MongoDB thinks in terms of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort I had not understood what you said.now yes. It works!